# I cant get a stepper motor to work with arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm using an arduino UNO with a L2989N motor controller with a nema 17 hanpose 17h3401 stepper motor. I'm using two 9 volt batteries in series to power it. I'm sure I connected them properly but it just doesn't work. I tried using the example stepper motor sketch stepper_oneRevolution but it didn't work. I just cant pinpoint what's wrong.
PS. I'm very new to this

Comment: standard 9V block batteries? They are not made for providing that much current. You need other batteries

Answer (score 1):

It is highly likely your power source supplies insufficient current to power both the stepping motor and the Arduino reliably.

This is very similar to one of my [past stackexchange question / answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/85856/mixed-sharp-ir-sensor-readings/85859#85859).

Where I say ...

> Consider using a power source which can supply more current.  For
> instance, [D size cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_battery) batteries can supply much more current than
> a [small 9 volt battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-volt_battery).

... all that said, stepping motors are high current devices.  It may not be feasible to run stepping motors off batteries.

Comment: Can you post a schematic as you have wired it showing all connections. You connect a lot of things but to what? Also post links to the hardware items. I did not find the L2989N motor controller.

Comment: @Gil, if you are asking questions of the O.P. then you might put your comment after the Question and not after the Answer. Then the O.P. might get a notification instead.

Comment: @김준호, do edit your original post instead of posting an answer.  Otherwise it is confusing as people can and do sometimes answer their own questions.  A L298 does not appear to have a 12v to 5v regulator.  But maybe there is one on the board you bought?  Do you have a link to that product?  What a battery can power depends on more than it's chemistry (LiPo) or voltage (14.8V).  Maybe try 2 different batteries.  One for the Arduino and another for the motor.  As a test if nothing else. Just so you know, some large steppers may need the likes of a motor cycle battery to keep running.